# The level of the logging module

Tags: python, logging

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger("test.conf")   
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)   

hterm =  logging.StreamHandler()    
hterm.setLevel(logging.ERROR)

hfile = logging.FileHandler("access.log")    
hfile.setLevel(logging.INFO)

formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')   

hterm.setFormatter(formatter)   
hfile.setFormatter(formatter)   


logger.addHandler(hterm)    
logger.addHandler(hfile) 

class test(object):
    def post(self):
        try:
            logger.info('right')
        except:
            logger.error('wrong')
```

why the log ('right') will be printed in the console, i have already set the level, is there any logic i miss?

if replace the class part with the following code , it can reach the aim of mine, but when i add a class, it doesn't work

```
    logger.debug("User %s is loging" % 'jeck')
    logger.info("User %s attempted wrong password" % 'fuzj')
    logger.warning("user %s attempted wrong password more than 3 times" % 'mary')
    logger.error("select db is timeout")
    logger.critical("server is down")
```

in the above code, it will print the critical and the error, and all the level will be written into the file.

Comment: What do you *expect* to happen when a logger is set to `DEBUG` level and you log an `info`?

Comment: i only want to show the level ERROR or CRITICAL in the console, and all the level will write into the file

Answer (score 0):

You are setting logging level DEBUG on logger and trying to log with info hence 'right' is getting printed. The order is:

> DEBUG -> INFO -> ERROR -> CRITICAL.

So if you are setting logging level to DEBUG, any level log proceding the DEBUG will be shown, your case. If you set logging level to ERROR, logs under error and critical will be shown and not under debug and info

Comment: emmm, but if i set the logging level to ERROR, only the ERROR or the CRITICAL will be written into the file, i don't want this

Comment: i set the streamhandler to the level ERROR, why the level below ERROR will be printed,it is  the biggest confusion to me.

Comment: you need to use another logger instance to do that , apparently you can't put different logging level for filehandler, different logger instance will solve your pusrpose

Comment: i set the ERROR to the streamhandler and the INFO to the filehandler. But if i create a new logger, the question may be solved